# CDC insert statement in postgres

Tags: postgresql, change-data-capture

I am trying to implement a statement where I update some timestamps and an active field in before inserting the new row.
In case the information  is identical, it should not do anything.

My statement looks like this:

```
with inputdata (id, name, inPrison)
as (
    SELECT * FROM (
        VALUES (
            1, 'egon',TRUE), (2, 'benny',FALSE), (3, 'kjeld',FALSE)) AS t (id,name,inPrison)
)
INSERT INTO public.cdc_test
           (id, NAME, inPrison,validfrom,validto,valid)
SELECT inputdata.id, inputdata.NAME, inputdata.inPrison, cdc.start, cdc.end, cdc.active
FROM inputdata 
cross JOIN (select now() as start, make_timestamptz(9999, 12, 31, 8, 00, 00) as end, TRUE as active) cdc
ON CONFLICT (id) WHERE md5(row(id,name)::text) != md5(row(public.cdc_test.id,public.cdc_test.name)::text)
DO UPDATE 
  SET valid = FALSE, 
      validto = excluded.validfrom 
      where active = TRUE
```

and the public.cdc_test table is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE public.cdc_test (
   id int NOT NULL,
   name char(100),
   inPrison BOOLEAN,
   validfrom DATE,
   validto DATE,
   valid BOOLEAN
);
```

I can run my statement without the on conflict, but the on conflict keeps giving me trouble and i feel like I exhausted the ideas I had to make this work.

Can anyone see what i am doing wrong?
When i run it, i get this error:
`invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "cdc_test"`

Answer (score 0):

Your `ON CONFLICT` should be after the `WHERE` clause, and the `WHERE` clause is related of the `SELECT` statement, not to the conflict handling

Here, your conflict handling is based on the `id` column (presumably a primary key on that table).

If you want to be able to handle `ON CONFLICT` on `md5(row(id,name)::text)`, then you need to create a `UNIQUE INDEX` on `md5(row(id,name)::text)` and use that expression on `ON CONFLICT (md5(row(id,name)::text))`.